# Does MySql support variable length file storing data type?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, rdbms

This is not a duplicate question as marked by **PM 77-1, Drew**
I have a simple question that if I want to store only 1MB file then do I need to use only MEDIUMBLOB (in this case 15 MB will be left free).

As we know that the **MEDIUMBLOB** stores file upto 16 MB, but as per my knowledge if I store a 1 MB file then 15 MB space for that row will be a waste.

*Is it correct?*

I want to store a specific 1 MB file for every user but didn't get any specific data type in MySql. *Do we have some data type that have the maximum 1 MB space?* or *Do we have any variable length data type ?*

Please revert.

Comment: "up to 16 MB".  It should not be wasting 15 Mbytes for a 1 Mbyte blob.

Comment: it is not leafing new data pages that aren't used

Comment: @Drew Could you please elaborate. I didn't get.

Comment: @rohit please read the answer to the duplicate question carefully and stop bombing this question with useless edits.